# Google Maps freezes with Chrome on elementary OS

Tags: google-chrome

I've had this problem on my desktop when I go to Google Maps on Chrome, it freezes and I can't move the map.

- Other browsers, such as the default that came with elementary OS Google Maps works.
- My laptop, which also runs elementary OS, Google Maps with Chrome works fine.
- I have the same extensions on my laptop as I do with my desktop Chrome.
- Resetting and clearing my browser did not work

Anyone know steps to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced severe lag in Google Maps until I disabled Hardware Acceleration (Settings > Advance Settings > Deselect setting under System.)